# Selecting all items in one table and join with another table, allowing nulls

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a requirement to select all values from the table birds (basically all birds), and then joining with another table which tracks who likes that bird.

So I want the query to return all birds, and ids of records where people like that bird. And if there is no record of anyone liking this bird, then that field should be null.

My current query isn't getting the nulls. Here it is:

```
select  bird_name, member_id 
from birds  
right join bird_likes on birds.bird_id = bird_likes.bird_id 
where member_id = 2 ;
```

What could I do to make sure each row in the birds table is getting displayed once?

Comment: Yeah I had tried it with the left join, but for some reason it still only returns the rows where there is a match, and not all rows from the left table.  Not sure what may be the problem.

Comment: if member_id is on the bird_likes table, you've found your culprit ;) see my answer for a working solution in this case.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

you must use `left join` instead of `right join`

### The different joins

`inner join` : keep only the rows where there's data in both table

`left join`  : keep all the rows of the left table and add what is possible from the right one

`right join` : keep all the rows of the right table and add what is possible from the left one

The left table is always the table we already have and the right table is the one we are joining with.

For the record, there is also a `cross join` which joins each row in the left table with each row in the right table, but this one isn't used very often.

I hope all this is now clearer for you :)

### Corrected query

```
select  bird_name, member_id 
from birds  
left join bird_likes on birds.bird_id = bird_likes.bird_id 
where member_id = 2;
```

Be aware that this assumes that the column `member_id` is in the bird table, otherwise you can keep the condition like this :

```
select  bird_name, member_id 
from birds  
left join bird_likes on 
    birds.bird_id = bird_likes.bird_id and
    bird_likes.member_id = 2;
```

Comment: I know the left join in supposed to work, but it is still returning only the rows where there is a match on the where clause, and not all the rows from the birds table :(

Comment: @Genadinik The where clause filter datas from all the table, check my second solution if member_id is in the bird_likes table, you must move the condition to the join in this case !

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT bird_name, member_id
FROM birds
LEFT JOIN bird_likes ON birds.bird_id=bird_likes.bird_id AND member_id=2
```

Answer (score 3):

You want to use `left outer join` in this case

```
select  bird_name, member_id 
from birds  
left outer join bird_likes on birds.bird_id = bird_likes.bird_id 
where member_id = 2;
```

This will return all bird names and 'null' for ones with empty likes.

Comment: This didn't return all the birds for some reason :(

Answer (score 1):

Change your RIGHT JOIN to a LEFT JOIN, that will bring in all `birds` records whether or not they have a relationship to `bird_likes`